# Ubuntu Server with persistant storage on a USB Flash Drive

Tags: server, usb-drive

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Server (not desktop) with persistent storage on a USB flash drive so I can use the drive and server in other desktops/laptops?

Comment: This seems to be a X-Y problem. Why don't you do a proper installation instead? There are ways to make it bootable on other machines and have supports both for uEFI and BIOS. A typical Ubuntu Server ISO is for installation only, not live.

Comment: Creating a persistent Live environment is not "installing"...which makes the question confusing.

Comment: If you use the drive on different computers, it is good to have a bootable Ubuntu USB that boots both BIOS and UEFI, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step. It might be good to start with the minimal install. I think you can also find Ubuntu Server image files on the internet that extract to a Full install